# PTIJ: Halachic car-buying advice needed

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Is it halachically permissible to purchase a Nissan during Adar?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: yes, but not a sea-van

Comment: What about a Genesis according to R' Eliezer?

Comment: @DonielF R' Eliezer would probably rather buy a Dodge Ram in Tishrei. Besides, it comes factory equipped with a horn.

Answer (score 15):

It is an explicit Gemara. The Gemara says in Brachos 10B:

> אָמַר שְׁמוּאֵל, אֵין מְעַבְּרִין אֶת הַשָּׁנָה בְּיוֹם שְׁלֹשִׁים שֶׁל אֲדָר, הוֹאִיל וְרָאוּי לְקוֹבְעוֹ נִיסָן.
>
> One cannot make a leap year on the 30th day of Adar, since it is a fitting time to buy a Nissan.

Thus, as per the Gemara, you may buy one.

Comment: that is only on the last day of adar what about the rest of adar sounds like no.

Answer (score 12):

No, mipnei sakanah. If you make an accident, you have to wait 2 months for the ER. (אייר)

Comment: Welcome! Thanks for the great first post!

Answer (score 7):

It is a Machloket…

Excerpt from Masechet Mashke-Shikur: Daf aleph, amud gimmel:

…. We learned in a Mishnah Rosh Hashanah 1:1 "....Nissan, Rosh HaShannah, L'Malachim (...Nissan, The head of the Year, for kings.")

Now, lets see, why would the Tanna of our Mishnah say "Nissan" and then say "The head of the year". Is it not repetitive? Nissan is the head of the year!

No.. If you will read it, read it like this: "Nissan (you must buy a "Nissan" ), on the head of the year, if you are a king."

So the Mishnah is teaching us that there is a mitzvah upon a king to buy a Nissan on Rosh Chodesh Nissan.

Mai Nissan? (What is a "Nissan") that the king must buy? Does not the Torah teach us that a king may not increase in money, wives, and horses? So what could this "Nissan" be, that the king must have it?

C'Dich'tiv (as it is written in a verse:) Megillas Esther 1:4 "When he showed the riches of his glorious kingdom, and the splendor of his granduer,.וְאֶ֨ת־יְקָ֔ר תִּפְאֶ֖רֶת גְּדוּלָּת֑וֹ

What is in fact the meaning of "the splendor of his granduer"? What riches did Achasverosh show them?

"V'es Y'Kar Tiferes Gedulaso" "And his car was the splendor of his grandeur"

So we learn out from here that a king must have a nice new car!

Therefore, when our Mishnah uses the word "Nissan" it must be a new car!

"Buy a Nissan, on Rosh Chodesh Nissan, if you are a king..."

and we learned in Berachos 10b: (King Hezekiah made a second Adar in Nissan!) : " He intercalated Nisan in Nisan, but the Sages did not agree with him.."

"Rather, Hezekiah erred with regard to the halakhic opinion ascribed in later generations to Shmuel, as Shmuel said: One may not intercalate the year on the thirtieth day of Adar, since it is fit to establish it as the New Moon of Nisan. "

So Why did the sages not agree?

Since the 30th of Adar was already assumed to be Nissan, then King Hezekiah already bought his new car that morning (to mekayem "zerizim makdimim l'mitzvos.") Later that day, however, he sought to re-establish it as merely the 30th of Adar (and make a second Adar starting the next day. Now Nissan would not occur until next month!)

The Sages held that one may not in fact buy a Nissan car during Adar! So Hezekiah would not be allowed to reverse the day to Adar after he purchased the new Nissan!

Hezekiah held on the other hand, that one may in fact buy a new Nissan car during Adar and had no problem reversing the day from a potential Rosh Chodesh Nissan back to Adar!

The Sages held, that since cars were given in this world mainly for the evildoers, (as it is written Numbers 23:4: "וַיִּקָּ֥ר אֱלֹהִ֖ים אֶל־בִּלְעָ֑ם "VaYakar Elokim el Billam.." "and Hashem gave a car to Billam.")

therefore, one must only buy a new car during the month of Nissan when it is a time of redemption and rejoicing, and when Moshiach is destined to come etc.

and Hezekiah? He held that since Purim falls in Adar, then we "darshan" the verse in Esther 8:16 " לַיְּהוּדִ֕ים הָֽיְתָ֥ה אוֹרָ֖ה וְשִׂמְחָ֑ה וְשָׂשׂ֖ן וִיקָֽר:"

"LaYehudim haysa orah vesimchah vesason viykar." "and for the Jews there was light and gladness and joy and **a car**!"

Comment: This is utterly ingenious and utterly insane. +1

Comment: Ha TY, I hope we continue to enjoy each others insanity and have a happy Purim ty !

Answer (score -1):

There are specific conditions that would allow you to do this:

- You need to be either a *Ba'al Teshuva* who is near the beginning of exploration of becoming more seriously religious

**OR** you need to be a convert

**AND**

You can only buy a Pathfinder

The reason for these conditions is that since you weren't previously aware of the restrictions and are finding your way, you would be considered an *oness*.

Answer (score -2):

You can buy it in adar but you have to wait until the zman t get ganah from it .